# Why does in_array() always return false (User Permissions)?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to make user permissions based of values in an SQL Database. I currently store user permissions in a `$_SESSION['Userpermissions']` array, however when I go to check these permissions, `in_array` always returns false.

I've already tried using the `isset` method and the `array_search` method.

Here is login.php

```php
function loginById($user_id)
{
    global $conn;
    $sql = "SELECT u.id, u.role_id, u.username, r.name as role FROM users u LEFT JOIN roles r ON u.role_id=r.id WHERE u.id=? LIMIT 1";
    $user = getSingleRecord($sql, 'i', [$user_id]);


    if (!empty($user)) {
        // put logged in user into session array
        $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
        $_SESSION['success_msg'] = "You are now logged in";
        // if user is admin, redirect to dashboard, otherwise to homepage
        if (isAdmin($user_id)) {
            $permissionsSql = "SELECT p.name as permission_name FROM permissions as p
                            JOIN permission_role as pr ON p.id=pr.permission_id
                            WHERE pr.role_id=?";
            $userPermissions = getMultipleRecords($permissionsSql, "i", [$user['role_id']]);
            $_SESSION['userPermissions'] = $userPermissions;
            header('location: ' . BASE_URL . 'admin/dashboard.php');
        } else {
            header('location: ' . BASE_URL . 'index.php');
        }
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

Here is the function to check the permissions

```php
 function canDeletePost() {
    if(in_array('delete-post', $_SESSION['userPermissions'])){
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
   }
```

Here is the output of `print_r`:

```php
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [permission_name] => delete-user
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [permission_name] => create-user
        )

)
```

And here's the code im using to test

```php
<?php if (canDeleteUser()){
                      echo "CAN DELETE USER";
                    }else{
                      echo "CANT DELETE USER";
                    }?>
```

The result is always "CANT DELETE USER"

Answer (score 2):

You are searching against the values in `$_SESSION['userPermissions']`, but those are arrays, not strings. Instead, use `array_column` to get the permission values out of the arrays:

```
in_array('delete-post', array_column($_SESSION['userPermissions'], 'permission_name'))
```